# Ruby on rails tutorial - integration test - valid/invalid user info sign failing - user_param issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm plugging away after an extended leave (a year) on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.  I'm getting a user_param error in an integration test.  I've gone to 4 sources trying to figure out where I'm going wrong on the strong parameters including the documentations.

Since starting up again last week, I have four hours generally getting to know the tutorial project and another twelve hours reading over chapters 7 to 12, then an hour chasing this problem.  I keep feeling like I must be scanning too quickly over this stuff & keenly realizing I am not good at tracing errors.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing?  I'd also like any tips on trouble shooting this type of thing too!  Thanks for your time!

Here's the error message I'm getting from console:

```
ERROR["test_password_resets", PasswordResetsTest, 2016-10-20 15:24:37 +0000]
     test_password_resets#PasswordResetsTest (1476977077.03s)
    NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
                app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:10:in `create'
                test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'
            app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:10:in `create'
            test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'

    ERROR["test_invalid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 2016-10-20 15:24:37 +0000]
     test_invalid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (1476977077.04s)
    ActionController::ParameterMissing:         ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: user
                app/controllers/users_controller.rb:52:in `user_params'
                app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `create'
                test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
                test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:52:in `user_params'
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `create'
            test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
            test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'

    ERROR["test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation", UsersSignupTest, 2016-10-20 15:24:37 +0000]
     test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation#UsersSignupTest (1476977077.05s)
    ActionController::ParameterMissing:         ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: user
                app/controllers/users_controller.rb:52:in `user_params'
                app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `create'
                test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
                test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:52:in `user_params'
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `create'
            test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
            test/integration/user_signup_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'

     FAIL["test_should_get_edit", PasswordResetsControllerTest, 2016-10-20 15:24:37 +0000]
     test_should_get_edit#PasswordResetsControllerTest (1476977077.05s)
            Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>
            test/controllers/password_resets_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsControllerTest>'
```

Here's the controller in question (users_controller):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

        # Before filters

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
              store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

        # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end



    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

Here's the user_signup_test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  end

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                         email: "user@invalid",
                                         password:              "foo",
                                         password_confirmation: "bar" } }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    assert_select 'div.field_with_errors'
  end

  test "valid signup information with account activation" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "Example User",
                                         email: "user@example.com",
                                         password:              "password",
                                         password_confirmation: "password" } }
    end
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    user = assigns(:user)
    assert_not user.activated?
      # Try to log in before activation.
    log_in_as(user)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
      # Invalid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path("invalid token", email: user.email)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
     # Valid token, wrong email
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_not is_logged_in?
      # Valid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
    assert user.reload.activated?
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
end
```

Here is the last controller - missed that one somehow ...

```
require 'test_helper'

class PasswordResetsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "password resets" do
    get new_password_reset_path
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Invalid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: "" } 
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Valid email
    post password_resets_path,
          password_reset: { email: @user.email } 
    assert_not_equal @user.reset_digest, @user.reload.reset_digest
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Password reset form
    user = assigns(:user)
    # Wrong email
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: "")
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Inactive user
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    # Right email, wrong token
    get edit_password_reset_path('wrong token', email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Right email, right token
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    assert_select "input[name=email][type=hidden][value=?]", user.email
    # Invalid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
            email: user.email,
                    user: { password:              "foobaz",
                            password_confirmation: "barquux" } 
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Empty password
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
           email: user.email,
                    user: { password:              "",
                            password_confirmation: "" } 
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Valid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
                    user: { password:              "foobaz",
                            password_confirmation: "foobaz" } 
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to user
  end
end
```

PasswordResetController:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,         only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]    # Case (1)

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?                  # Case (3)
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)          # Case (4)
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'                                     # Case (2)
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove `params` key before `user` parameters, e.g.:

```
test "invalid signup information" do
  get signup_path
  assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
    post users_path, user: { name:  "",
                             email: "user@invalid",
                             password: "foo",
                             password_confirmation: "bar" }
  end
  assert_template 'users/new'
  assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
  assert_select 'div.field_with_errors'
end
```

Also you can debug received parameters in controller with [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry):

- add gem `pry` to your Gemfile (if there is no one);
- run `$ bundle install`;
- add `binding.pry` in controller before method `user_params` is called;
- check that `params` contains expected parameters.

Comment: Nailed it thank you!  Did so for both of those ... not sure where to poke the other one - but awesome & fast response!  Still lingering issues with the: "test_password_resets", PasswordResetsTest & the "test_should_get_edit", PasswordResetsControllerTest

Comment: PS:  For anyone else using Michael Hartl's guide as of 11/1/2016, the syntax allowed has changed since the last revision for the params & also the rake/rails commands are not correctly listed for console frequently.